# how do I translate this javascript code

Tags: javascript

how can I change this code to change my email address.

Thank You for your time reading my request.
Anis

```
<div class='footer'>
<p>All images copyright :copyright: 2007–2018
<script type="text/javascript">eval(unescape("%63%6b%63%78%6f%34%39%3d%5b%27%25%36%31%25%36%65%25%36%39%25%37%33%25%37%30%27%2c%5b%27%25%36%33%25%36%66%25%36%64%27%2c%27%25%36%39%25%36%33%25%36%63%25%36%66%25%37%35%25%36%34%27%5d%2e%72%65%76%65%72%73%65%28%29%2e%6a%6f%69%6e%28%27%2e%27%29%5d%2e%6a%6f%69%6e%28%27%40%27%29%3b%6b%63%6a%78%71%34%33%3d%27%41%6e%69%73%20%50%61%6e%6a%77%61%6e%69%27%3b%64%6f%63%75%6d%65%6e%74%2e%77%72%69%74%65%28%6b%63%6a%78%71%34%33%2e%6c%69%6e%6b%28%27%6d%61%69%27%2b%27%6c%74%6f%3a%27%2b%63%6b%63%78%6f%34%39%29%29%3b"));</script>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Urldecode it, change it, encode it back?

Comment: `java` != `javascript`

Comment: which decoder you used

Comment: @VenkiWAR Seems pretty clear, no?!

Comment: Thank You for the prompt reply Sir.a few years ago I paid someone on oDesk to make this come about as my name, Anis Panjwani and my email address. Now I would like to make some changes to this information and wanted to learn how to make these small changes myself/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For those playing at home: double-encoded.

```
ckcxo49=['%61%6e%69%73%70',['%63%6f%6d','%69%63%6c%6f%75%64'].reverse().join('.')].join('@');kcjxq43='Anis Panjwani';document.write(kcjxq43.link('mai'+'lto:'+ckcxo49));
```

Unreversed:

```
anisp com icloud
```

Come on: it’s just url-encoded. Show some initiative.

Comment: Dave my friend, to me this is like 5th grade French and I don't speak any.

Comment: I'd like to keep the same code by change my last name from Panjwani to Roshan and keep the same email address.   so Anis Roshan

Comment: @AnisPanjwani You might not even need to learn JS to do this; encoding and decoding can be done online, e.g., https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/. Plug some of your snippet into there and see what happens. There’s also an encoder to go back to where you are now. You’ll need to encode the new email values, put those into the top snippet, then encode the entire thing again.